# Dynamic "skill badge" level

Tags: game-design, achievements, serious-games

I am currently working on a serious game that is currently published, with regular update (new content, bug fux, ...)

We have "episodes" composed of 3 mini games, each based on a skill to acquire (so 3 different skills in one "episode").

Currently, the player does not have a lot of feedback about skills, and we want to address that by adding a "skill badges" mechanism : at the end of an episode, if a player has succeeded a mini game, he will earn a skill badge associated with the mini game.

Now, we have a lot of different skills in the game, some appear a lot of times, other are more specific and only appear once/twice in the game. New one can appear after an update, and of course, the number of appearance of each skill can (will) evolve at each update, so a skill that appear only once in the game today might be used more in the future.

We wanted to add badge level (bronze / silver / gold), but we can't figure out how to implement this.
If a skill appear 7 times in the app, it's easy to divide it, for example that way :
1 successful mini game : bronze
3 : silver
6-7 : gold

But what happen about skills that appear only once ? Do we only unlock bronze level for now ? or should it be another unique level ?

If you get a unique level on one skill, what happen when there will be more occurrence of that specific skill ? Do player keep their badge level, or is it transformed into a bronze level ?

If one skill is in the game 3 times and we have 1:bronze, 2:silver, 3:gold, someone is gold, and then we update the game, and now the skill is in the game 7 times, what happen ? Is it now silver, or still gold ? I feel like both are bad, because in the first time you are losing progress, and in the other, you don't have incentive to continue playing.

What do you think about it ?
Best solution would be a solution where we don't have to manage that aspect at each update, but where we have strong rules that takes care of what should happen in each situation.